# Failed to load fluent-ffmpeg in a react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, ffmpeg

I am trying to use [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) in my Typescript React application.

I have installed it using `npm i @types/fluent-ffmpeg --save`,
and I have import it to my project using `import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg'`

But I got the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg' in '/Users/yifanwang/code/clideo-clone/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg'
```

How can I fix it? Thank you very much if you can help! :)

Comment: The package doesn't use ESM, try using require instead? Also did you install the package as well as the types?

Comment: Using require also produce the same error. I have installed the original package as well as @types, but it didn't work. :(

Comment: Looks like there's an open PR to fix the issue. https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/pull/1138 See also this issue https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/573